# Animation keeps rendering same frames

Tags: rendering

When I got every setting in place for rendering the frames to images, I noticed that not that many changes were happening in between the frames. Here is frame 30, a rendering of smoke that looks exactly like the first frame rendered. When I switch the type of cache from Replay to Modular, the smoke does not show up on any of the rendered frames. If you have any suggestions for making the frames render how they should, please let me know.

Comment: Can you check the FPS. If it is not set to the default that might be a problem.

Comment: Yeah it's 24 fps right now.